# deleting row from Dataframe results in distribute dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframe nbr2:

```
    Postal_Code     Borough     Neighborhood
0   M1B     Scarborough     Rouge, Malvern
1   M4C     East York   Woodbine Heights
2   M4E     East Toronto    The Beaches
3   M4L     East Toronto    The Beaches West, India Bazaar
4   M4M     East Toronto    Studio District
5   M4N     Central Toronto     Lawrence Park
```

On applying below code to filter out rows:

```
neighbor = nbr2.drop(nbr2[nbr2['Borough'].str.contains("Toronto")==False].index, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

the dataframe gets distributes like below:

```
  Postal_Code           Borough  \
 37         M4E      East Toronto   
 41         M4K      East Toronto   
 42         M4L      East Toronto   
 43         M4M      East Toronto   
                                         Neighborhood  
37                                        The Beaches  
41                     The Danforth West\n, Riverdale  
42                   The Beaches West\n, India Bazaar  
43                                  Studio District\n
```

below code also results in similar structure:

```
# define the dataframe columns
column_names = ['Postal_Code','Borough', 'Neighborhood'] 
# instantiate the dataframe
neighbor = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

neighbor = nbr2.drop(nbr2[nbr2['Borough'].str.contains("Toronto")==False].index, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please ignore the numbering I changed it to fit in window, we can do reset for that.

Comment: I have this on top of my code  -- import pandas as pd # library for data analsysis
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)` how about this?

Comment: perfect, Thanks @anky_91

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```